# Edit Webpart properties with dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I would like to Add a dropdownlist to edit webpart properties and bind it with all document library list available in sharpoint 2010.

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: i want  to add a dropdownlist to edit propety web part in sahrepoint ,and bind this dropownlist with dymanic data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create **Custom Web Part Editor** with DropDownList

[Creating a Custom Web Part Editor in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx)

and using SharePoint Object Model to fill this dropdownlist like this (not tested):

```
SPListCollection docLibraryColl = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl) 
{
    SomeDropDownList.Items.Add(list.Title, list.Id);
}
```